# How to handle writing to database and responding in API server asynchronously?

Tags: python, node.js, api, asynchronous

I would like to create a simple API to receive a request from a user and respond immediately. Then I would like it to record the data from the request into my database and I'd like to do this after responding so the user is not blocked.

I'm wondering if it's possible to handle this problem without resorting to using a queue and also where the database write does not block the response. I've implemented something like this before using a queue but I have a rather simple use case. I was thinking of implementing this API in python but I'm also open to using node.js, but I'm wondering if the non-blocking I/O in node.js refers to database writes and will solve my problem like I think it will.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: This can certainly be done easily in node.js.